# Trisecting a semicircle gives a trisection of a line segment

Tags: geometry

A semicircle is constructed outwards on side $BC$ of an equilateral triangle $ABC$ as an diameter. Given points $K$ and $L$ which divide the semicircle in $3$ equal arcs. Prove that lines $AK$ and $AL$ divide $BC$ in $3$ equal parts.

Comment: Notice BK=KL=LC = 1/2 and the distance from A to the midpoint of KL is $\sqrt {3}/2 +\sqrt {3}/4$ .  So the center third of BC is so that $x/(1/2) = (\sqrt {3}/2)/(\sqrt {3}/2 + \sqrt {3}/2) $.  Solving you get x=1/3.

Comment: Terrible title.  It gives almost no sense of what the problem is about.  As I explained on another of your posts, the problem statement belongs in the body of the Question, but the title should give Readers an idea what the problem is about.

Answer (score 1):

Let AK, AL cuts BC at M and N respectively.

[image]

The pink triangle is similar to the green triangle and they are in the ratio 2 : 1.

Therefore, CN : NO = 2 :1.

Answer (score 1):

Let AB=BC=AC=2.  Let M be the midpoint of BC.  Then MBK,MKL, and MLC are equilateral triangles with sides of length 1.

Let AK cut BC at D  and AL
cut BC at E.  Let P be the midpoint of KL.

Triangle ADE and AKL are similar.  So DE/KL = AM/AP.

KL=1.  AM = $\sqrt {3}.$ MP = $\sqrt {3}/2$.  So AP = $\sqrt {3}(1+1/2) $

Solving DE = 2/3. Or 1/3 of BC.

ADE is clearly isoceles.  So DE is central to BC.

So AD=DE=EC=2/3= 1/3 of BC.

Answer (score 0):

Extend $BK$ and $CL$ until they intersect at their common point of intersection $A^*$. Since the three arcs are equal, $\angle \, BCA^* = \angle \, BCL = \angle \, CBL = \angle \, CBA^* = \frac{2}{3} \big(\frac{1}{2}\text{arc}(BKLC) \big) = \frac{2}{3} 90^{\circ} = 60^{\circ}$. Therefore triangle $A^*BC$ is equilateral and congruent to $ABC$.  Furthermore, $C\angle \, CLB = \angle \, BKC = 90^{\circ}$ because $BC$ is the diameter of the arc $\text{arc}(BKLC)$, which means that $L$ and $K$ are midpoints of $CA^*$ and $BA^*$ respectively. Let $M$ be the intersection point of $AA^*$ and $Bc$. Then since $ABC$ and $A^*BC$ are congruent equilateral triangles sharing a common edge $BC$, the quadrilateral $ABA^*C$ is a rhombus, so $M$ is the midpoint of both $AA^*$ and $BC$  and $AA^*$ is perpendicular to $BC$. Consequently, $AA^*B$ and $AA^*C$ are congruent isosceles triangles. Since $BM$ and $AK$ are medians in $AA^*B$, their intersection point $G_B$ is the centroid of $AA^*B$. Since $CM$ and $AL$ are medians in $AA^*C$, their intersection point $G_C$ is the centroid of $AA^*C$. By congruence of $AA^*B$ and $AA^*C$, segments $BG_B = CG_C$ and $G_BM = \frac{1}{2}BG_B = \frac{1}{2}CG_C = G_CM$ and thus $G_BG_C = BG_B =CG_C$.